# RSolveValue syntax

Tags: syntax, difference-equations

Can't see anything wrong with this:

```
sol4 = RSolveValue[{a[n + 1] - 1.2*a[n]*(1 - a[n]) == 0, a[1] ==0.1}, 
  a[n], n]
```

But I just get an echo from Mathematica

Comment: "an echo from *Mathematica*" - that usually means it doesn't know a closed-form solution, if it exists.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyhow

Comment: Solution in Graph: `s1 = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] - 12/10*a[n]*(1 - a[n]) == 0, a[1] == 1/10}, a, {n, 1, 20}] // N; ListStepPlot[s1]`